# Passing a bound value as an argument to a SwiftUI 2 View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've got a radial slider which works with this somewhat wordy code:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var object: Object
    @State var parameter: Double = 0 {
        didSet {
            object.some.nested?.parameter = Int(parameter)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        RadialSlider(value: $parameter, label: "my parameter")
            .onAppear { parameter = Double(object.some.nested?.parameter ?? 0) }
            .onChange(of: parameter) { object.some.nested?.parameter = Int($0) }
    }
}
```

As I need to use this slider multiple times, I'd like to omit the `onAppear` and `onChange` lines (with the help of a ViewModifier for example). But I don't know how to go about passing my `parameter` to the RadialSlider so that it maintains the binding. The type of `object.some.nested?.parameter` can vary between being an Int and a String.

Alternately, Is there a simpler way to bind the value from my object to my radial slider's UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize parameter in `init`, like

```
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var object: Object
    @State var parameter: Double {        // << no initial value !!
        didSet {
            object.some.nested?.parameter = Int(parameter)
        }
    }

    init(object: Object) {
       self.object = object
        _parameter = State(initialValue: Double(object.some.nested?.parameter ?? 0))
    }

    var body: some View {
        RadialSlider(value: $parameter, label: "my parameter")
            .onChange(of: parameter) { object.some.nested?.parameter = Int($0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems more wordy (except in the view itself). Is there an advantage to doing it how you suggest though? Ultimately I was hoping for something like this... RadialSlider(value: $parameter, label: "my parameter", param: object.some.nested?.parameter)

Comment: Also... Why the underscore in the initializer? I'm getting "return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" when I include the underscore and "Cannot assign value of type 'State<Double>' to type 'Double'" when I don't.

Comment: Just forgot to assign internal object. With such deep hierarchy of Object, it does not seem appropriate to use binding (moreover with optionals).

Comment: Cool. Works now! Congrats on reaching 100K reputation (you were on 99.9 when you helped me yesterday). :-)